# Почему отдается файл на скачивание размером 0 байт?

Tags: php, http

```
$filePath = 'http://example.com/files/video.mp4';

stream_context_set_default(
                            [
                              'http' => [
                                          'method' => 'HEAD'
                                        ]
                            ]
                          );
$headers = get_headers($filePath);
// если файл найден на сервере
if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
{
    header($headers[6]); // Content-Length
    header($headers[8]); // Content-Type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='video.mp4');
    readfile($filePath);
}
```

В результате отдается файл 0 байт.
Проблема где-то в stream_context_set_default(), если убрать проверку с запросом HEAD тогда все хорошо.

Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Эм.. Пропущенный апостроф не хочешь поставить на место?

Comment: @Qwertiy дело не в этом, с крипте путь генерируется с переменных, просто забыл поставить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция [stream_context_set_default()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-context-set-default.php) устанавливает контекст потоков по умолчанию. В том числе это влияет на работу функции `readfile()`.

Можно переопределить метод `HEAD` на `GET` той же функцией `stream_context_set_default()` после выполнения

```
$headers = get_headers($filePath);
```

чтобы `readfile()` возвращала тело файла.

Comment: Так может сразу посылать проверку на существование через GET или это затратно по времени?

Comment: Если вы с чужого сервера качаете файл, то наверное лучше использовать для функции get_headers() метод HEAD. Думаю, вероятность бана вашего ip будет ниже.

Comment: @Plush, да, лучше для get_headers() использовать метод HEAD. Протестил на локахосте Если не указать HEAD, то скачивается весь файл.

Comment: То есть, все-таки, это единственный верный путь: проверять существование файла через HEAD-запрос, потом возвращать по умолчанию вновь GET и уже после отдавать файл на скачивание браузеру?

Comment: @Plush, `проверять существование файла через HEAD-запрос, потом возвращать по умолчанию вновь GET и уже после отдавать файл на скачивание браузеру` так наименее затратно, я считаю.

Comment: Прочитал, что можно передать параметр прямо в функции, как-то так: `readfile($filePath, false, stream_context_create(['http' => ['method' => 'GET']]));`, правильно ли здесь использовать создание контекста потока `stream_context_create` или что-то другое? Наглядных примеров в мануале не нашел, потому и сомневаюсь.

Comment: @Plush, так делать нельзя. Третий параметр это не контекст потока, а указатель на ресурс.

Comment: Visman, то есть передавать туда метод `GET` (чтобы отдавалось тело файла) будет неправильным? В мануале пишут что это указатель на ресурс с контекстом потока. Подсмотрел пример передачи для функции в http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php, там третий параметр передается как `Корректный ресурс контекста, созданный с помощью функции stream_context_create()`

Comment: @Plush, извиняюсь, вчера при тестировании опечатку у себя допустил, в результате в ответ 500 ошибка выдавалась. Да, функция `stream_context_create()`  принимается 3 параметром для `readfile()`.

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что из-за того, что метод `head` не предполагает наличия тела у ответа. Посылаются все заголовки, какими они были бы у `get` (в том числе `content-length`), но тело не отправляется.

Comment: `HEAD` используется только для проверки существования файла и возвращает правильные заголовки с размером файла и типом контента они и передаются в файл на скачивание. А вот в `readfile($filePath);` уже указывается точный путь к файлу и по прямой ссылке он доступен. Разве что `stream_context_set_default()` что-то перезаписывает.

Comment: @Plush, ответ с телом на head-запрос нарушает спецификацию http. Его суть заключается в том, чтобы узнать только заголовки. Если тебе нужно пересылать данные, используй get.

Comment: Мне нужно отдать файл пользователю. Проверить что он существует и отдать браузеру на скачивание.

Answer (score 0):

HEAD - это специальный метод, позволяющий получить HTTP-ответ в виде одних заголовков, проигнорировав (не включив) сам документ в ответ. Другими словами, вы сами просите сервер отдать вам заголовки и ничего другого. Для получения документа целиком вам нужен GET.